# Inequality check of input not working properly

Tags: python

I have a function where the user inputs values of x_1 and x_0, however I want to make sure that if x_1 and x_0 are less than 0 or greater than R(some constant), it prints the appropriate error message. Right now, regardless of x_0 and x_1 it still prints the first error message.

```
G = 6.6741*10**-11
r_e = 6371000
r_m = 1737100
M_e = 5.9722*10**24  
M_m = 7.3420*10**22
R = 3.8440*10**8
w =  2.6617*10**-6
#defining a function such that f(r)=0#
def f(x):
    if x==0:
        return ('undefined')
    return (G*M_e)/x**2 - (G*M_m)/(R-x)**2 - w**2 * x

def sec(x_0,x_1):
            if x_1 or x_0>=R:
                print ('x_0 or x_1 must be less than R')
                raise SystemExit
            if x_1 or x_0<=0:
                print ('x_0 or x_1 must be greater than 0)
                raise SystemExit
            while x_0!=x_1:
                y=x_1-f(x_1)*(x_1-x_0)/(f(x_1)-f(x_0))#secant loop#
                x_0=x_1
                x_1=y
                print (x_1)
                if y==x_0:
                    print ('First Lagrange Point found to be {:5.4e}m from 
the Earth'.format(x_1))#print answer#
                    break
```

Output:

```
 sec(0,1)
 x_0 or x_1 must be less than R
 An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit

C:\Users\jainv\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:3304: UserWarning: To exit: use 
'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)



sec(10**7,10**8)
x_0 or x_1 must be less than R
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit

C:\Users\jainv\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:3304: UserWarning: To exit: use 
'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
```

in both those cases the initial x_1 and x_0 were less than R but I still got the 'must be less than R' error.

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `if x_1>=R or x_0>=R:` and `if x_1<=0 or x_0<=0:`

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
if x_1 or x_0>=R:
```

and this:

```
if x_1 or x_0<=0:
```

#### should be:

```
if x_1>=R or x_0>=R:
```

and:

```
if x_1<=0 or x_0<=0:
```

Otherwise it evaluates `if x_1` separately which will only occurs when `x_1 != 0` or `True`.